# Как правильно загружать шаблоны?

Tags: javascript, mvc

Использую данный метод для получения содержимого html файлов-шаблонов:

```
var Net = new function() {
this.viewsPath = "views";

//Получение схемы отображения
this.GetView = function(viewName) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: this.viewsPath + "/" + viewName + ".control",
      cache: false
    }).done(function (view) {
        return view;
    });
}
```

Далее мне необходимо загрузить несколько вьюшек и сообщить через callback, когда все будет загружено. Делаю таким способом:

```
var Views = new function() {
this.Category = "";
this.Products = "";
this.Product = "";
this.ProductExtended = "";
this.ProductCard = "";
this.ReviewGrid = "";
this.Contacts = "";
this.Comparison = "";

this.Load = function(ready) {
    $.when(Views.Category = Net.GetView("category")).done(function () {
        $.when(Views.Products = Net.GetView("products")).done(function () {
            $.when(Views.Product = Net.GetView("product")).done(function () {
                $.when(Views.ProductCard = Net.GetView("product-card")).done(function () {
                    $.when(Views.ReviewGrid = Net.GetView("review-grid")).done(function () {
                        $.when(Views.Contacts = Net.GetView("contacts")).done(function () {
                            $.when(Views.CategoryPopup = Net.GetView("category-popup")).done(function () {
                                $.when(Views.Comparison = Net.GetView("comparison")).done(function () {
                                    $.when(Views.ProductExtended = Net.GetView("product-extended")).done(function () {
                                        ready();
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Выглядит ужасно, посоветуйте пожалуйста, как можно осуществить это более вменяемым способом